# Loop that iterate througth different variables with similar names

Tags: c#, loops

I have this code, wich seems too repetitive, so I wanted to use a loop to make it better:

```
            //Converts a text in a integer using a custom method based on int.TryParse
            int a1 = determinantes.aEntero(a1Box.Text);
            int a2 = determinantes.aEntero(a2Box.Text);
            int a3 = determinantes.aEntero(a3Box.Text);
            int b1 = determinantes.aEntero(b1Box.Text);
            int b2 = determinantes.aEntero(b2Box.Text);
            int b3 = determinantes.aEntero(b3Box.Text);
            int c1 = determinantes.aEntero(c1Box.Text);
            int c2 = determinantes.aEntero(c2Box.Text);
            int c3 = determinantes.aEntero(c3Box.Text);
            //I pass those new ints to a method to do something with them
            resultado.Text = determinantes.detGrado3(a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3).ToString();
```

The first part could be done using arrays a[1], a[2]... but I'd need to change the names of the variables to make the start with the same letter.

The second part I have no clue of how it can be done. I though doing something like

```
 a[counter] = determinantes.aEntero(a[counter]Box.Text);
```

But obviously that won't work. So, dou you have any ideas how I can use a loop in that code?

Thanks ;)

[UPDATE]
I'm having the same problem in the code of a "clear" button, too:

```
        a1Box.Text = "";
        a2Box.Text = "";
        a3Box.Text = "";
        b1Box.Text = "";
        b2Box.Text = "";
        b3Box.Text = "";
        c1Box.Text = "";
        c2Box.Text = "";
        c3Box.Text = "";
        d1Box.Text = "And so on till the infinite!";
```

[UPDATE] 
Finally I've come to this. I think it's right now. Thank you all guys!

```
TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[] { a1Box, a2Box, a3Box, b1Box, b2Box, b3Box, 

c1Box, c2Box, c3Box };
int[] enteros = new int[boxes.Length];

for (int f = 0; f < boxes.Length; f++) {
    enteros[f] = determinantes.aEntero(boxes[f].Text);
}

resultado.Text = determinantes.detGrado3Arr(enteros).ToString();
```

Comment: I haven't understood the reason to not use an array

Comment: Exactly what @Steve said, create your `TextBox` objects in a collection/array: `a[0] = new TextBox();`. Then you just loop through all of them.

Comment: You could use a list, fill it with all the objects (a1Box, a2Box etc.). Select all Text properties using a linq query.

Comment: Are all your textboxes you want to add up in a Panel or can be placed in a panel for instance?

Comment: @user1628733 they are in a tableLayoutPanel.

Comment: @gmiley I'm looking for more information to do it that way. I'm just started C# a few weeks ago.

Comment: @miguelamacias What you want to use here are arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say throw the text values into an array, loop through that, and assign to a second array, then tell your consuming function to take it as a parameter.

Pseudo:

```
string[] boxes = new string[] {a1box.Text, a2box.Text, ...etc etc ...lastbox.Text};
int[] results = new int[boxes.length];
for(i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
     results[i]= determinantes.aEntero(boxes[i]);
}
resultado.Text = determinantes.detGrado3(results)  
//you should return a string 
//instead of using the ToString() method if possible`
```

Also, there's a built in way to handle your 'clear' issue.

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
   if(c.GetType = typeof(TextBox))
   { ((TextBox)c).Clear(); } //or ((TextBox)c).Text = string.Empty, if you prefer  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> So, do you have any ideas how I can use a loop in that code?

You put all your similar variables into a container (array or `List<>` might be the easiest) and then loop over them.

As a general programming hint: when you notice yourself giving numbers to variables, stop and use a container.

Comment: The general programming hint should be put together with all the others that are "lessons learned" somewhere. Although I'm sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

This may not meet your exact needs but it will be close to what you want, I think.

```
int total = SumTextBoxesInPanel(pnlMyTextBoxes);

resultado.Text = determinantes.detGrado3(total).ToString();

public int SumTextBoxesInPanel(Panel pnl)
{
  int total = 0;
  foreach(TextBox txt in pnl.Controls.FindAll((ctrl) => ctrl is TextBox))
  {
     total += determinantes.aEntero(txt.Text)
  }

  return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ints = new Dictionary<TextBox, int>();
foreach(var tb in new[] {
       a1Box, a2Box, a3Box, a4Box, a5Box, ... , anBox})
   ints.Add(tb, determinantes.aEntero(tb.Text));
```

to get the integer value for any box,

```
var x = ints[a1Box];
```

but even better, just do it dynamically... create an extension on TextBox.

```
 public int IntegerValue(TextBox this tb)
 { return determinantes.aEntero(tb.Text)); }
```

then, anywhere in your code you can just get the integer value by writing `a1Box.IntegerValue()`

```
  var x = a1Box.IntegerValue();
```